# In PHP, How to search and match a specific string with JSON data?

Tags: php, json, pattern-matching

I have a bunch of strings and I want to know if they exist in the JSON response.

I used the following code but it is not working. I do not want to loop through the JSON data.

```
 $url  = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=".$session['access_token'];
 $page=file_get_contents($url);
 $json_a = json_decode($page,true);

 $pos = strpos($page, $mystring);
 if($pos == true)
 {
     do something
 }
```

$page does not contain a string with the contents of the JSON feed. How to convert JSON to string so I can check for $mystring ?

EDIT:

This is strange. 
When I use the url https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=".$session['access_token']

I get empty data, but when I use "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$session['access_token'];

Everything is fine and I get the list of all my friends. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong?

This is the link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
I used the exact url format for Profile feed (Wall): https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=...

Comment: you say $page goes not contain the JSON string, which it should if you want to do a json_decode on it. Check the return value of file_get_contents because it returns false on error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JSON *IS* a string, until you run it through the decode function and its gets converted to a php structure. You should be able to do

```
if (strpos($page, "your search string") !== FALSE) {
    echo "hey, it's in there"; 
}
```

If your $page is coming out blank, then your file_get_contents call is failing somehow.

Comment: I used echo file_get_contents($url);                                 The output I am getting is {"data":[]} instead the actual data embedded in it

Comment: No... That's a JSON string representing an object, with one key value pair. The key being "data" and the value being an empty array.

Comment: I think your question has diverged a lot from the original. It might be worth creating a new one.

Comment: This answer cleared some fundamental doubts though. Will open a new question to resolve the issue.

Comment: Well, `{"data":[]}` is a valid json representation, that's something coming back from Facebook. So something's wrong with your access token, and facebook's returning "Nothing" (would be nice if they had an error section that explains why, though)